# adding image material to irregularly shaped plane

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to be able to add an image to an irregularly shaped plane.

I have an imported svg ...
[image: svg]

transformed to geometry (plane)
[image: geometry nodes]

an image ...
[image: raster]

and I want to apply an image texture (preferably via nodes) ...
[image: shader nodes]

I've tried marking seams and unwrapping with mixed success though the process seems too convoluted and requires a lot of manual work within the uv editor recreating the face.

Part of the problem is ignoring the transparent pixels of image texture and only applying visible pixels to shape ... is that possible?

eventually the face will be displaced with another raster (dem) image which I have working fine in the context of a rectangular shape ...
[image: alternative]

any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: okay, a bit embarrassing, tho the generic way (without geometry nodes) is working fine now ... no idea how I screwed up ... but if anybody could show me how I can automate uv unwrapping within geometry nodes?

Comment: Issue resolved, tho would be nice to have an answer for automating this, ie purely geometry nodes. [![uv on irregular shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg4cO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg4cO.png)